# excel - transpose (rows to columns) with extra dimension?

Tags: excel

is it possible to transpose rows to columns with extra dimensions??

imagine table:

```
dimension |  data 1 |  data 2 | data 2
---------------------------------------
  test    |     a   |    b    |
  dummy   |     c   |    e    |   x
  user    |     a   |    d    |
john doe  |     v   |         |
```

I need to get this:

```
dimension |  data 
-------------------
  test    |     a  
  test    |     b  
  dummy   |     c
  dummy   |     e
  dummy   |     x
  user    |     a
  user    |     d
john doe  |     v
```

Is there any built-in function? Or do I need to use macro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert matrix to 3-column table ('reverse pivot', 'unpivot', 'flatten', 'normalize')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal)

Comment: oh yeaaah :) pivot table :D thx ... that helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is more straightforward with VBA, though it can be done using worksheet formulas along, viz:

Assuming your source table is in `A1:D5` (with headers in row 1), enter this **array formula**** in `F2`:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTIF(B$2:D$5,"<>"),"",INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),1+MMULT(0+(ROW(B$2:D$5)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(B$2:D$5))),MMULT(0+(B$2:D$5<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B$2:D$5)^0))))))`

Copy down until you get blanks for the results.

Then enter this formula in `G2`:

`=IF(F2="","",INDEX(INDEX(B$2:D$5,MATCH(F2,A$2:A$5,0),),COUNTIF(F$2:F2,F2)))`

Copy down as required.

Note that this set-up assumes that it is not possible for a given *dimension* to have blank entries in between non-blank entries within the data columns, for example *data1* and *data3* are non-blank but *data2* is blank. This is the case for the data you provided so seems like a fair assumption.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*